# Is it valid to answer -almost- the same thing answered in a comment?

Tags: discussion, answers, comments

This is my first ever post on Meta, I tried to search for a similar question, but found none. Anyway, I was browsing around SO and find a question (which is now deleted) that asked a very basic thing. One of the moderators answered in a one-line comment the solution the OP was looking for.

A few minutes later, a user comes and make an answer with almost the same thing (with even the content of another comment that the moderator did, with further clarification).

Is this a valid thing? I thought that this is all about answering OP's question (it doesn't matter if it is in a comment or in an answer). I mean, if the answer has already been answered in a comment (specially if it is a very basic one), what's the point of making a separate answer saying what has already been told?

Thanks for the clarification :)

Comment: I've seen this situation happen in the past, however, normally it's the same user who'll give the user a quick comment on their suggested fix before writing about their fix in detail within the answer itself. It seems to be in poor taste to expand on what another user has commented *unless* they're adding/contributing a lot more to the solution with good explanations and details.

Comment: Speaking as someone who frequently answers questions using a comment, I don't care at all if someone else posts a similar answer.  It can be time consuming to write a good answer and you often don't know if the OP will even respond.  To me at least, it is not a problem.

Comment: According to site guidelines, answers should not be in comments. So it's completely valid for someone to write an answer that contains information in a comment. Especially if they, as you describe, expand on the information. If the person who puts an answer in a comment doesn't want to take the time to write out an answer, that's their decision. But comments are "ephemeral" - they get deleted. Useful information belongs in an Answer.

Comment: If a questions is very basic it may well  have been asked and answered before. In that case, the correct action is to close as a duplicate. Under such circumstances, someone might put a quick hint/answer in a comment rather than write out an answer.